# Styling Lost After AsyncPostBack in Update Panel

Tags: css, updatepanel

When I put some controls in an update panel, the styling is lost after the trigger control button is clicked. It seems like the css in not being applied after the asyncpostback. Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your css is being applied via javascript or jquery on document ready.

Which doesn't fire when .net does an ajax request.  You need to reapply the styling on the "page_loaded" event

Like so

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(addCss);
    function addCss() {
        //do stuff
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The css is being applied to all the checkboxes, dropdownlists without specifying the css class. In the css file, it specifies to be applied to all such controls.